# Android Dev in Eclipse: Strange Error Message

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

I created a test project and added two XML files.  When I save the project, I get an error message that doesn't make any sense.

> [2011-11-10 10:21:04 - Testing] res\layout\MainList.xml: Invalid file
>   name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>
> [2011-11-10 10:21:04 - Testing]
>   res\layout\MainList.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only
>   [a-z0-9_.]
>
> [2011-11-10 10:21:04 - Testing]
>   res\layout\PlaylistEditor.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only
>   [a-z0-9_.]
>
> [2011-11-10 10:21:04 - Testing]
>   res\layout\PlaylistEditor.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only
>   [a-z0-9_.]

The filenames do not have any invalid characters.  Eclipse DOES save the project (including these files) so why does it throw this error message?

Comment: your question is your answer it is saying only[a-z] [0-9] and only "_" character is valid any capital letter is invalid.

Answer (score 7):

Your XML files can't contain upper-case characters in their names. Rename `MainList.xml` to `mainlist.xml`, etc. This is an Android requirement, not an Eclipse one.

Comment: ok thanks.  Had no idea!  I just do that out of habit as it makes it easier to read.